Как запустить команду с принятием соглашения в консоли?
Поднимаю сервис для генерации сертификата:
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    command: certonly --webroot -w /usr/share/nginx/html -m my@email.ru -d example.ru -d www.example.ru
    volumes:
      - ./certbot:/usr/share/nginx/html
    networks:
      - my-network

И он останавливается, требуя согласиться с соглашением:
2024-05-21 18:44:01 Please read the Terms of Service at
2024-05-21 18:44:01 https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.4-April-3-2024.pdf. You must agree in
2024-05-21 18:44:01 order to register with the ACME server. Do you agree?
2024-05-21 18:44:01 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
2024-05-21 18:44:01 (Y)es/(N)o:

Читал доки - там написано, что надо указать -m перед email. Он указан. Может, я что-то пропустил?

Опция -m указывает почту, а для согласия с условиями есть --agree-tos (и разумеется это есть в справке)
